# How to send Asynchronous URL Request?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I would like to know how do I get a return value 1 or 0 only.... back from an URL request asynchronously.

currently I do it in this way:

```
NSString *UTCString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://web.blah.net/question/CheckQuestions?utc=%0.f",[lastUTCDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSLog(@"UTC String %@",UTCString);
NSURL *updateDataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UTCString];
NSString *checkValue = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:updateDataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:Nil];
NSLog(@"check Value %@",checkValue);
```

this works, however it is blocking my main thread till I got a reply back from the URL, how do I set it so it will do it in a another thread instead of the main thread ?

**EDIT: ANSWER**
I end upcalling my function with this, it works well :)

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(shouldCheckForUpdate) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: As of iOS 5, you can use `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue*) queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*)) handler` instead, which is easier and clearer for simple requests than creating a delegate object. I'll try to write up an answer showing this method later.

Comment: @MarkAmery It would be nice to see your answer. I'm having difficulty finding a simple example of `sendAsynchronousRequest`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can use `NSURLConnection` class

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

and handle its response and errors using its delegate methods.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

You can find implementation of NSURLConnection

- [Apple docs: Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
- [How To Use iOS NSURLConnection By Example](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)

Edit: Although `NSURLConnection` is provided by apple is more recommended way of placing URL request. But I found [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library very time saving, easy to implement and robust yet simple as third party implementation. You should give it a try.

Comment: which method should i use to get the cookie values ??

Answer (score 24):

try this :

.h:

```
NSMutableData *responseData;
```

.m:

```
- (void)load 
{
  NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
  responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
  [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
  [responseData release];
  [connection release];
  [textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
  NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData
                                                   length]);
  NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: i just need the a reply of 1 or 0, is this too much for it ?

Comment: @Maulik Add "Smart Developers" Room.

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSURLConnection` and make your request.
Then you may start synchronous or asynchronous connection with NSURLConnection's methods :

Loading Data Synchronously

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

Loading Data Asynchronously

```
+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:
– start
```

Check the `NSURLConnection` class in Apple Developer API Reference.

Comment: here's the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly copy from https://gist.github.com/knmshk/3027474. All credits go to https://gist.github.com/knmshk.

```
xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
@"http://forrums.bignerdranch.com/smartfeed.php?"
@"limit=NO_LIMIT&count_limit20&sort_by=standard&"
@"feed_type=RSS2.0&feed_style=COMPACT"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                           if (error) {
                               xmlData = nil;
                               NSLog(@"error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
                           }
                           [xmlData appendData:data];
                       }];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the iOS XCode documentation called LazyTableImages.  This does an asynchronous URL as well as asynchronous image load into `UITableView` cells displayed on the screen after scrolling stops.  Excellent example of protocols, asynchronous data handling, etc.