# ios: requestWithURL method happen in separate thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Simple question, but I cant find the answer: Does requestWithURL happen in main thread or is a new thread created?

I have this in viewDidLoad (main thread):

```
    //Get the current table view controller page
    UIWebView *webController= [MoreTabPages objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *urll =[NSURL URLWithString:[websites objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSURLRequest *firstReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urll];
    [webController loadRequest:firstReq];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question aims at whether the main-thread will still be running while the URL-request is made.
Look at asynchronous requestWithURL, that'll most likely do what you like.

(look at this SO-post: [how to send Asynchronous URL Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515667/how-to-send-asynchronous-url-request))

Comment: ok, but you cant call loadRequest for UIWebview as it requires a NSURLRequest. Any way to get around this?