# Encode an image URL to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I would like to take an image from a URL:

```
http://imgur.com/gallery/ihHQvP1
```

and then convert it NSData so that I will be able to parse it up to the server. The server only accepts NSData and not image links. I have the following from the camera:

```
 NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self scaleImage:activityImageView.image toSize:CGSizeMake(230, 230)]);
```

it is then put into a JSON format to send to the server:

```
jsonPostBody= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"activity_id\":\"%@\",\"user_id\":\"%@\",\"activity_title\":\"%@\",\"activity_category_id\":\"%@\",\"activity_description\":\"%@\",\"activity_image\":\"%@\",\"activity_begindate\":\"%@\",\"activity_enddate\":\"%@\", \"activity_time\":\"%@\", \"activity_email\":\"%@\",\"activity_city\":\"%@\",\"activity_where\":\"%@\",\"gotooffer_url\":\"%@\",\"latitude\":\"%@\",\"longitude\":\"%@\"}",[editActivityDict valueForKey:@"activity_id"],singletonObj.userID,title,selectedCategoryString,discription,[Base64 encode:pictureData],begindateConvert,enddateConvert,milatryTime,@"",city,where,entersite,singletonObj.singletonlatitude,singletonObj.singletonlogitude];
                    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ROOT_URL,EDIT_ACTIVITY];
```

As you can see the variable for the picture being sent in the body post is:

```
[Base64 encode:pictureData]
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:) to fetch the data returned by performing a GET request to that URL as a `NSData` instance. This, however, perfoms a *synchronous* web request, which is not recommended to be performed on the main thread to avoid blocking the UI.

To avoid a synchronous fetch on the main thread, you could put the same code in a background thread using GCD or operation queues, but the safest way is to use `NSURLConnection`/`NSURLRequest` as is described in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515791/1045904).