# Cell text overlapping when scrolling in UITableView Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Everytime I start scrolling in the `tableView` the subtitleLabel text keeps overlapping each other in every row. I've tried for the last 4 hours every single search on the Internet for this problem I have clicked and tried.

Here is my `ViewController.m`:

```
@interface ANViewController()
{

    NSMutableArray *TitleLabel;
    NSMutableArray *SubtitleLabel;
    NSMutableArray *AvatarImages;

}

@end


@implementation ANViewController

@synthesize thetableview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.thetableview.delegate = self;
    self.thetableview.dataSource = self;

    TitleLabel = [NSMutableArray array];
    SubtitleLabel = [NSMutableArray array];
    AvatarImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    __block NSArray *posts;

    __block NSData *allNewsData = nil;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        allNewsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: API_URL]];
        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *allNews = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allNewsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            posts = allNews[@"data"];
            for (NSDictionary *newsPost in posts) {
                [TitleLabel addObject:newsPost[@"title"]];
                [SubtitleLabel addObject:newsPost[@"post_message"]];
                NSString *avatarUrl = AVATAR_URL;
                NSString *avatarExt = @".jpg";
                [AvatarImages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", avatarUrl, newsPost[@"user_id"], avatarExt]];
            }
        }
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"THIS IS THE MAIN THREAD...");
            [self.thetableview reloadData];
        });
    });

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: WEBSITE_URL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    long count = TitleLabel.count;
    if(count == 0){
        count = 1;
    }
    return count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier;
    ANTableViewCell *Cell;
    if(TitleLabel.count == 0){
        NSLog(@"Did with no news");
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell_NoNews";
        Cell = [thetableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (Cell == nil) {
            Cell = [[ANTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        Cell.noNewsLabel.text = @"No news to display!";
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Did with news");
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        Cell = [thetableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (Cell == nil) {
            Cell = [[ANTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        Cell.TitleLabel.text = [TitleLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Cell.SubtitleLabel.text = [SubtitleLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[AvatarImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        Cell.AvatarImage.image = img;
    }

    return Cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` for `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, and you need an asynchronous connection instead of a synchronous like you're doing: `NSData *allNewsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]];` in your `viewDidLoad` method that is blocking your main thread.

You can adapt this code to your need, in order to download it on the background:

```
__block NSData *allNewsData = nil;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    allNewsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: API_URL]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: WEBSITE_URL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"THIS IS THE MAIN THREAD...");
        [self.thetableview reloadData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Try increasing the row height to see what happens.

Comment: Where is that? I dont see it.

Comment: On your Storyboard or xib file.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Why do you [Cell removeFromSuperview]; ? Try removing this line.

Comment: Oh that was there for testing, I removed it in the new code I just updated.

Comment: Try to hard code the subtitle to see if it still happens, like this cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"subTible...";

Comment: I ended up just making 15 of the same prototype cells and using a different name for each, and that works.

Comment: You know what, actually thats just a bitch way to get out of this problem. im going to solve this the right way.

Comment: Yes, keep working on the problem because all hacks that we make to solve problems on the short run will return to bite us in the future.

Comment: Ok so it seems when I hardcode it the issue goes away.

Comment: Yes, then the issue seems to be on the way you're getting your data from.

Comment: So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I think the problem is NSData *allNewsData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]]; because it's a synchronous connection. You need an asynchronous connection on the background. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515667/how-to-send-asynchronous-url-request

Comment: Now I see that you're blocking the main thread, and that's why you're having this issue.

Comment: What do I do to fix it then?

Comment: All User Interface related stuff runs on the main thread, so if you're making a download on it you'll block the User Interface.Try modifying the code I'll put on my answer.

Comment: You have to use __block NSData *allNewsData = nil;

Comment: I get this error in console now when trying to load the app now: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`

Comment: You need to rearrange the code to make it happen in the proper order so you pass the data only when it's ready. Sorry, but I need to go now. I hope you can fix it now and tomorrow I can try to help you more if you don't.

Comment: I still haven't been able to make it work no :/ 
The app doesn't start and it gives a console error of ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`

Comment: Ok so I was able to get it all working, and the issue is still happening. I updated the code in my post with the latest code.

Comment: Still doesnt work, btw that webView is for something else not the table view.

Comment: I just ended up making the background of the label white, and it doesn't show the overlapping text anymore. Its the only thing I can do at this point. I still accepted your answer for the help. Thanks :).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I had fun trying to solve the problem with you. Sometimes it's just like that, and we only find the best solution after a while. I hope you have a great success with your project.